# Does indirect child inherit the color property in css?

Tags: css, reactjs

So, I am basically having this problem where I am trying to change the font color of all the child elements inside a tag- direct or indirect. 
I don't know if it shouldn't be inheriting that property but it is not working in my case. I am putting the style of the parent `color:"white"` but unless it is a direct child text it is not changing the color.

```
export const NgoBar = () => {
    return (
        <div style={{backgroundColor:"red", width: "55vw", margin:"auto", color:"white"}}>
            Some text
            <div style={{display:"flex",flexDirection:"column",backgroundColor:"red", padding:"10px"}}>
                <span>Some different text</span>
                <span>From somewhere</span>
            </div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This gives the result
[image]

It doesn't change the text of the children element - just the direct text of itself. And I find it a bit odd. So just to change the color of all the text inside a parent element, I have to go to all the element and add a personal styling to give it a white text. Just wanna know is it usual ? If yeah then how to turn all the text inside a parent element to white.

Comment: Try using a class for that. You are using react, there you can easily use styledComponents for example.

Comment: None seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

In your way you apply color only to the current tag. It's an inline style. See below. Font color is inheritable:

```css
.container {
    color: green
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> Some text
  <div> <span>Some different text</span> <span>From somewhere</span> </div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This thing is not working for my react app. I gave the name `className="somethign"` and tried to work it out but no.

Answer (score 0):

Then try this:

```
.container div,
.container span {
    color: green
}
```